# LINQ - Find all items in one list that aren't in another list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I'm stuck with a LINQ query (or any other efficient means of accomplishing the same thing).  Can someone show me how I can select all the items in one list that are not present in another list?

Basically, I have a list I formed by matching items between two other lists.  I need to find all the items in the first list that matches weren't found for.  Can someone fill in the stars in the second LINQ query below with the query that would achieve this goal?  If I were using TSQL, I would do `SELECT * NOT IN ()`, but I don't think LINQ allows that.

```
//Create some sample lists.
List<IdentifierLookupData> list1 = new List<IdentifierLookupData> { /*Init */ };
List<IdentifierLookupData> list2 = new List<IdentifierLookupData> { /*Init */ };

//Find all items in list1 and list2 that match and store them in joinItems.
var joinItems = (from d1 in list1
    join d2 in list2 on d1 equals d2
    select d1).ToList<IdentiferLookupData>();

//Find all items in list1 not in joinItems.
var deletedItems = (from d1 in list1
     ***select all items not found in joinItems list.***
```

Comment: Your exact title searched in google: http://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=LINQ+-+Find+all+items+in+one+list+that+aren't+in+another+list

Comment: @JoeTuskan And yet the question received up votes!

Comment: I can find anything on google, SO is a good site because I can type a question in 30 seconds, work on something else, and get the perfect expert-argued answer later without wasting any time or using the possibly inefficient first google answer and wasting time finding that out myself while I'm getting paid to get things done :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use LINQ to get items in one List<>, that are not in another List<>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Try using `.Except` extension method [<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
var result = list1.Except(list2);
```

will give you all items in `list1` that are not in `list2`.

IMPORTANT: Even though there's a link provided to MSDN docs for the method, I'll point this out here: `Except` only works out of the box for collections of primitive types, for POCOs/objects you need to implement IEquatable on that object.

Comment: But only if `IdentifierLookupData` implements `IEquatable<IdentifierLookupData>`

Comment: This answer really ought to be edited to say *Except only works out of the box for primitive lists, for POCOs/objects you need to implement IEquatable on that object.

Answer (score 39):

Try this:

```
var List2 = OriginalList.Where(item => !List1.Any(item2 => item2.ID == item.ID));
```

Comment: I like this one because I can use it for two different types of lists, like with Dates. where I need to filter out the original list based on another list. +1

Comment: I like this one too, because of the possibility to compare different types of lists. Great!

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is to use the `Except` method.

```
var deletedItems = list1.Except(joinItems);
```

This will return the set of items in `list1` that's not contained in `joinItems`