# How to return records not found in both lists using c# and linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to linq, and I'm really struggling to get a result from two lists where the records doesn't exist in the second table.

I two classes...

- cfiles

  - Year
  - session
  - centre
  - fileNameRaw
- cfileRecs
  -Id

  - fileName

cfiles, contains all pdf files in the repository, which cfilesRecs contains a database entry for each pdf file.

Both classes are presented as List and List, and I would like to return a list containing only the files not found in cfilesRecs using linq.

Here is the code used, although as you probably see the linq syntax is wrong.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<cfileRecs> dbScanRecords = dbRecords();    // Contains db records for objects
        List<cfiles> awsScanObjects;                   // Contains objects from aws
        using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listing objects stored in a bucket");
            awsScanObjects = ListingObjects();
        }

        List<cfiles> abc = from d in dbScanRecords join aws in awsScanObjects on d.fileName == aws.fileNameRaw

    }
```

Example answers deal mainly with comparing to lists of the same type - rather than joining two different lists on a common property value.

Thanks everyone for the examples, but they don't seem to produce the correct result I've created a dotnetfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/MW6gXF illustrating the problem. The result returns 6 items, where I should be getting only 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ - Find all items in one list that aren't in another list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418942/linq-find-all-items-in-one-list-that-arent-in-another-list)

Comment: Do you want both missing and redundant records? I.E. left join or full join?

Comment: All I need is to return a list of the filenames in awsScanObjects that are not in dbScanRecords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Where()` in combination with `Any()` to achieve this:

```
var result = awsScanObjects.Where(x=> !dbScanRecords.Any(y=> y.filenameRaw == x.filename));
```

Comment: this would not compile due to `y.filenameRaw =x.filename` you have to use the equals operator `==`

Comment: When I tried this, I get an error for everything inside the where clause - unknown method Where?

Comment: Have you included System.Linq namespace

Comment: Yes System.Linq namespace included.

Comment: Can you reproduce in Dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: I've not used Dotnetfiddle before tbh.  I'm getting a similar problem with any solution I try, for example...                                                                   from dbs in dbScanRecords
                                    join aws in awsScanObjects on dbs.fileName equals aws.fileNameRawinto into g
                                    from result in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    where result == null
                                    select dbs).ToList();  dbs, awsScanObjects and aws are all shown as unknow variable types - using correct...

Comment: Then you have  some other issue in your solution

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = awsScanObjects.Where(r => !dbScanRecords.Any(r2 => r2.fileName == r.fileNameRaw));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var files = dbScanRecords.Select(x => x.fileName).ToList();

result = awsScanObjects.Where(x => !files.Contains(x.fileNameRaw)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To find files that exists in AWS but not in dbrecords.

```
private class cfileRecs
        {

            public int Year { get; set; }
            public string session { get; set; }
            public string center { get; set; }
            public string fileNameRaw { get; set; }

        }

        private class cfiles
        {
            public string FileName { get; set; }
        }

List<cfileRecs> dbScanRecords = new List<cfileRecs>() { 
                new cfileRecs(){ center = "a", fileNameRaw ="abc.pdf", 
                session="aaa", Year=1999}};    

List<cfiles> awsScanObjects = new List<cfiles>() { 
                new cfiles(){ FileName = "abc.pdf"},
                new cfiles(){ FileName = "bbb"}
            };

var filesNotFound = (from files in awsScanObjects
                  join recs in dbScanRecords 
                  on files.FileName equals recs.fileNameRaw into grp
                  from g in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new { dbfile = g == null ? null : g.fileNameRaw,
                  awsfile = files.FileName })
                   .Where(x => x.dbfile == null).ToList();
```

fileNotFound contains AWS record with filename = "bbb", which is not found in dbrecord

Comment: filesNotFound contains the total records in awsScanObjects - there a circa 55,000 files in awsScanObjects and dbScanRecords contains 9,600 records, so I was expecting a resultset of around 45,000 ish

Comment: I have updated the code with mock up data and query result. I hope this helps.

Comment: It returns the number of files - I've tried to set this up in DotNetFiddle, not sure how to share though.  Found it https://dotnetfiddle.net/MW6gXF

Answer (score 0):

//I understand that u want to find files that exists in AWS but not in dbrecords.

var filesNotFound =

(from files in awsScanObjects join recs in dbScanRecords

on files.FileName equals recs.fileNameRaw into grp

from g in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()

select new { dbfile = g == null ? null : g.fileNameRaw, awsfile = files.FileName })

.Where(x => x.dbfile == null).ToList();

Comment: This returns the same number of rows as awsScanObjects (55,000 ish), there are roughly 9,600 rows in dbScanRecords - so I expected around 45,000 ish.