# LINQ Comparing two list and putting the results into one list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a C# application. I have two lists ('NewStock' and 'OldStock') of the same custom type, 'Book'. I want to extract any 'Book' object that is the list NewStock but not in the OldStock list into a new list called ResultList. Please see an example below. How do I do this?

I have used implemented the IEqualityComparer interface on my class Book so that I check if a book object is equal to another.

```
 NewStock      OldStock
 A             A
 B             C
 C            
 D
```

Result I would like,

```
ResultList
B
D
```

Comment: `var results = newStock.Except(oldStock).ToList()` and you can provide a custom comparer to `Except` to do this.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth make that an answer

Comment: Maybe related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list

Comment: @NathanKoop Done, though I expect this to be closed as a duplicate. These usually are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var results = newStock.Except(oldStock).ToList()
```

And you can [provide a custom comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `Except` to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use except to do this:

Example can be found here:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
List<Book> ResultList = NewStock.Select(x=>!OldStock.Contains(x)).ToList();
```