# Return a List<t> that has items that do not exist in a List<t>

Tags: c#, list, class, return, compare

In C#, I have the following Class:

```
public class SQLColour
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CorporateID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<SQLColour>` called List1 and a `List<SQLColour>` called List2.

How can I return a `List<SQLColour>` that has items that have an ID that exists in List1 but not in List2?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the following pattern, as [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.except%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does not accept a generic predicate:

```
// Find all IDs in List2, using a HashSet to improve bounds
var idsList2 = new HashSet(List2.Select(x => x.Id));

// Select from List1 only elements which ID does not appear in List2
var onlyList1ById = List1.Where(x => !idsList2.Contains(x.Id));
```

The HashSet is not required but it has better bounds and is thus my standard pattern.