# C# LINQ select from where value is not contained in array / list

Tags: c#, linq

New to LINQ and not sure on the correct syntax for what I want to do.

I have a "Blocklist", an array or list (could be either) of bad codes that I don't want put into this new "keys" list that I am making

currently...

```
var keys = (from s in context.Keys
            where s.Code != "BadCode1"
            where s.Code != "BadCode2"
            where s.Code != "BadCode3"
            where s.Code != "BadCode4"
            where s.Code != "BadCode5"
            orderby s.Name
            select s).ToList<Keys>();
```

how would I trim it down to one line and have it read from the "blocklist" ?
so more like...

```
var keys = (from s in context.Keys
            where s.Code != ANY OF THE VALUES FROM "BLOCKLIST"
            orderby s.Name
            select s).ToList<Keys>();
```

Answer (score 26):

Add it to an array and then use `Contains`:

```
var badCodes = new[] { "BadCode1", "BadCode2", "BadCode3", "BadCode4", "BadCode5"};

var keys = (from s in context.Keys
            where !badCodes.Contains(s.Code)
            orderby s.Name
            select s).ToList<Keys>();
```

Answer (score 22):

All other answers are correct, but I'm personally a fan of this:

Assuming that you have a list of strings called `blackList` containing all strings you want to filter out.

```
var keys = context.Keys.Where(x => !blackList.Contains(x.Code))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    .ToList();
```

I just like the way this makes my code readable and easy to understand. But again, every other answer is correct.

Answer (score 12):

```
var keys = (from s in context.Keys
    where !blackList.Contains(s.Code)
    orderby s.Name
    select s).ToList(); // do you really need the ToList?
```

> an array or list (could be either)

If you're doing this in memory (linq to objects) then a `HashSet` would perform better than either an array or a list. If you're doing it in a database then it won't make any difference.

Also, do you really need it to be in a list? If you're going to loop through the results or otherwise do something for which `IEnumerable<>` or `IQueryable<>` will serve on its own, you're probably better leaving it out.

Answer (score 7):

Create a `List<string>` with all invalid values

```
List<string> sBlackList = new List<string>(){"BadCode1", "BadCode2", "BadCode3"};
```

and replace

```
where s.Code != ANY OF THE VALUES FROM "BLACKLIST"
```

with

```
where !sBlackList.Contains(s.Code)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [Except Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) similar to this:

```
var badCodes = new[] { "BadCode1", "BadCode2", "BadCode3", "BadCode4", "BadCode5"};

var blackList = context.Keys.Where(s => badCodes.Contains(s.Code));
var filteredKeys = context.Keys.Except(blackList);
```

Comment: this requires 2 requests to the database. How about _RandomStranger_ 's approach?

Answer (score 5):

For detect intersection of any collections you can use .Contains() method.
Its simply:

1) determine you blackList:

```
var blackList = new List<string> {"BadCode1", 
                                  "BadCode2", 
                                  "BadCode3", 
                                  "BadCode4",
                                  "BadCode5"};
```

2) filter the request by the intersection with the blackList (!blackList.Contains(s.Code)):

```
var keys = (from s in context.Keys
            where !blackList.Contains(s.Code)
            orderby s.Name
            select s).ToList<Keys>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a list of codes of black list and check if it does not contain relevant codes

```
var keys = (from s in context.Keys
            where !blackList.Contains(s.Code)
            orderby s.Name
            select s).ToList<Keys>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put all badcodes in a Hashset, and look for values not in "blacklist-hashest"

there is a good example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3944821/1117305