# Use Linq to get Items in List that do not have a match in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of employees, and a list of employeeGroups.  I am trying get a list of employees that do not have a matching record in the employeeGroups list.  I tried using the example found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list) but it is not working for my needs and I can't figure out how to change it to get the desired list.  The result is always NULL.

Here is my code:

```
        List<ModuleView.EmployeeBO> employees = EmployeeBA.Employee_GetList_All(DB_Context, IsActiveChoice.Active, IsEnabledChoice.Enabled);
        List<PortalView.EmployeeGroupBO> groups = SecurityDA.EmployeeGroup_GetList_All(DB_Context);
        List<ModuleView.EmployeeBO> result = employees.Where(p2=> !groups.Any( p=>p.EmployeeId == p2.EmployeeId))  as List<ModuleView.EmployeeBO>;
        return result;
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the `as List<ModuleView.EmployeeBO>`. The `.Where()` method always returns an `IEnumerable<>` that's lazily evaluated, not a `List<>`. To get this to work, simply change that to `.ToList()`.

Comment: That was EXACTLY the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might try this.
I did not get a chance to test the code.

```
List<ModuleView.EmployeeBO> employees = EmployeeBA.Employee_GetList_All(DB_Context, IsActiveChoice.Active, IsEnabledChoice.Enabled);
List<PortalView.EmployeeGroupBO> groups = SecurityDA.EmployeeGroup_GetList_All(DB_Context);
List<ModuleView.EmployeeBO> result = employees.Where(p2=> !groups.Any( p=>p.EmployeeId == p2.EmployeeId)).ToList();
return result;
```