# How to select table value in linq entities?

Tags: linq, lambda, entities

**DATABASE 1:**  BOOK -  **TABLENAME1:** BOOKINFORMATION1 (ID,NAME)

**DATABASE 2:**  BOOK2  **TABLENAME2:** BOOKINFORMATION2  (ID,NAME)

I want to select bookınformation1 id and then bookınformation2 id.I to select the ones with equal linq and I would like to add equal values to the other table(**other table name:bookınformation3**).I take error this code.How to solve this problem.

```
var query1 = datatable1.AsEnumerable().Select(a => aID.ToString() }); 
var query2 = datatable2.AsEnumerable().Select(b => bID.ToString() });

var exceptAB = query1.Except(query2);

DataTable dtMisMatch = (from a in datatable1.AsEnumerable()
                           join ab in exceptAB on a.ID.ToString() equals 
                          ab.ID
                           select a).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck? Can you select the rows you need? Can you insert into the other table?

Comment: Did you try searching online for `Linq Select` and `Linq Except`?

Comment: @nvoigt Hi.I select this 2 table  table1.ID=table2.ID. This query is linq entities.But not select ID.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list