# get all elements that does not exist in a c# list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of numbers:

```
List<int> lstActive = new List<int>{1,6,7,8,10};
```

I want to get the numbers that does not exit in the above list and less than 10
e.g.

```
private List<int> GetInactive(List<int> lstActive, int MaxValue)
{
//To Do
}
```

Then:

```
List<int> lstInactive = GetInactive(lstActive, 10)
```

the result should be:
{2,3,4,5,9}

How can I do this ?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list

Comment: Also, you don't have to pass an array to the `List<int>` constructor. You could built it like so: `List<int> lstActive = new List<int> { 1, 6, 7, 8, 10 };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue).Where(n => !lstActive.Contains(n))
```

If perf is an issue, make a hashset:

```
var hs = new HashSet<int>(lstActive);
Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue).Where(n => !hs.Contains(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
List<int> lstActive = new List<int>(new int[]{1,6,7,8,10}); 
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList().Except(lstActive).Dump();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hyiAhs

Comment: thank you @ppau2004, I as well didn't understand it. It would be  very nice if downvoter explains us :)