# Use LINQ to remove items in List<object> where a property exists in List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

This question is *very* similar to this one:  [Use LINQ to get items in one List<>, that are not in another List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list).  But the differences are just enough that I'm having trouble nailing down the LINQ syntax.

I have two lists:

```
List<Fubar> fewBarNew
List<string> existingProviderIDs
```

Where `Fubar` looks like:

```
Class Fubar
{
    int FunbarId int {get; set;}
    ....
    ....
    string ProviderID {get; set;}
}
```

Now, I want to remove from `fewBarNew` any instance where `FewBarNew.ProviderID` exists inside `existingProviderIDs`.

```
 fewBarNew = fewBarNew.Where(f => !existingProviderIdList.Any(ep => ?????).ToList();
```

Comment: SInce you want to compare ProviderIDs, `f.ProviderID==ep`

Comment: @Rango that's LINQ

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Which LINQ method is it using?

Comment: @Servy Enumerable.Contains?

Comment: @Rango and the difference is ... ? O(n^2) either way, full enumeration either way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The difference is one is a LINQ method and one isn't.  Thus there are no LINQ methods in that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any enables you to check if any item in a collections matches some predicate. So you could define the predicate to be "if any item matches the current":

```
fewBarNew.Where(f => !existingProviderIdList.Any(ep => ep == f.ProviderID));
```

However, I think a cleaner way will be to use `.Contains`:

```
var result = fewBarNew.Where(f => !existingProviderIDs.Contains(f.ProviderID));
```

Then, as this performs in `O(n^2)` you can improve using a `HashSet<string>` instead:

```
var existingProviderIDSet = new HashSet<string>(existingProviderIDs);
var result = fewBarNew.Where(f => !existingProviderIDSet.Contains(f.ProviderID));
```

As `HashSet`'s `Contains` performs an `O(1)` operation, this will execute in `O(n)`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on performance as well, in addition to just the answer!

Comment: @GiladGreen I do the `.Where` thing all the time; but I've never done the HashSet. While I understand the `.Contains` is O(n), I wouldn't think this counters the cost of the creation of the HashSet (in time and resource consumption) where you already have the List. Am I misunderstanding? Or are you just suggesting that the HashSet would have been a better choice from the outset?

Comment: @Clay - it is very case dependent. I've have a list of ~200k items and a second which was also quite big. For that case it was very much worth it to create the hash-set and then use it. Best is to create a scenario where you populate two lists like this with different numbers of items and plot the execution time. Then you will see how much is the overhead of creating the hashset compared to the added value in performance

Comment: @Clay `O(N)` is the cost for a *single* `List.Contains` call. When you perform a `Contains` for every item in the other list, the cost is `O(N^2)`. [HashSet.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) is O(1) though. At some point, the cost of repeated `List.Contains` calls will become larger than the initial cost of creating the HashSet