# Linq not equal to returning all values in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

Good Morning. I have a list *"changes"* from which I'm getting data from 2 datatables whereby *"Item" from datatable 1* is equal to *"ItemCode" from datatable 2* as shown below.

```
            var changes = (from dr1 in dtItemSicorax.AsEnumerable()
                           from dr2 in dtItemCloud.AsEnumerable()
                           where dr1.Field<string>("Item") == dr2.Field<string>("ItemCode")
                       let sum = dtItemSicorax.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Item") == dr2.Field<string>("ItemCode")).Sum(dr => dr.Field<decimal>("Quantity"))
                       select new
                       {
                           ID = dr2.Field<int>("ID"),
                           ItemName = dr2.Field<string>("ItemName"),
                           ItemCode = dr2.Field<string>("ItemCode"),
                           Qty = dr2.Field<int>("Qty"),
                           UpdatedQty = dr2.Field<int>("Qty") - sum,
                           ItemCodeName = dr1.Field<string>("Item"),
                           ItemQuantity = dr2.Field<int>("Qty") - sum,
                           InvoiceDate = dr1.Field<DateTime>("InvoiceDate"),
                           Sum = sum * -1,
                       }).GroupBy(x => x.ItemCodeName).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

This is working fine.
I am now creating another list where I want to get data from the 2 datatables whereby *"Item" from datatable 1* is **equal not to** *"ItemCode" from datatable 2*.

I am using the following code:

```
            var sicochanges = (from dr1 in dtItemSicorax.AsEnumerable()
                               from dr2 in dtItemCloud.AsEnumerable()
                               where dr1.Field<string>("Item") != dr2.Field<string>("ItemCode")
                           let sumzero = 0
                           select new
                           {
                               ID = dr2.Field<int>("ID"),
                               ItemName = dr1.Field<string>("Item"),
                               ItemCode = dr1.Field<string>("Item"),
                               Qty = sumzero,
                               UpdatedQty = sumzero - Convert.ToInt32(dr1.Field<decimal>("Quantity")),
                               ItemCodeName = dr1.Field<string>("Item"),
                               ItemQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(dr1.Field<decimal>("Quantity")),
                               InvoiceDate = dr1.Field<DateTime>("InvoiceDate"),
                               Sum = sumzero - Convert.ToInt32(dr1.Field<decimal>("Quantity")),
                           }).GroupBy(x => x.ItemCode).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

The list "sicochanges" is returning all items from the datatables instead of only those *"Item" from datatable 1* which are **equal not to** *"ItemCode" from datatable 2*.

**EDIT 1**

In Datatable 1, I have the item CADMIXAUTR06850 which is not found in Datatable 2.
In Datatable 3, I'm trying to display all which is not common in them. But datatable 3 is displaying all items as shown in the picture.

[image]

Where am I faulting in my linq?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any sample data and an example of what you want as output? It strikes me that potentially most of the items in dr2 will have an ItemCode that isn't equal to an Item from dr1.

Comment: I updated the question please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question but I try to simplify your question;

Here we have sample data;

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { 1, "a" }, { 2, "b" }, { 3, "c" }, };
var d2 = new Dictionary<int, string>() { { 1, "x" }, { 2, "y" }, { 3, "z" }, };
```

First query;

```
var query1 = (
    from _d1 in d1
    from _d2 in d2
    where _d1.Key == _d2.Key
    let s = 0
    select new { k1 = _d1.Key, v1 = _d1.Value, k2 = _d2.Key, v2 = _d2.Value, }
);

var group1 = query1.GroupBy(x => x.v1);
var result1 = group1.Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Second query;

```
var query2 = (
    from _d1 in d1
    from _d2 in d2
    where _d1.Key != _d2.Key
    let s = 0
    select new { k1 = _d1.Key, v1 = _d1.Value, k2 = _d2.Key, v2 = _d2.Value, }
);

var group2 = query2.GroupBy(x => x.k1);
var result2 = group2.Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

- At 1st query, you don't need `GroupBy` and `Select` sections. `ToList` is enough. query1 and result1 has exactly the same output.
- 2nd query does outer join and selects only first items of groups. It selects all d1 items but outer joins d2 items. It selects 1-2, 2-1, 3-1. I assume you get why it selects these values.
- If your datagrid records does not have itemcodes that share the same itemname, it does not matter if you group your data by itemcode or itemname.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a left join to match up the Item and ItemCode values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37320016/4693920), with the following code

```
List<string> inList1ButNotList2 = (from o in list1
                               join p in list2 on o equals p into t
                               from od in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               where od == null
                               select o).ToList<string>();
```

The important line here is `where od == null` which gets the items that don't match, `where != null` would get items that do match.

Microsoft also has [examples of joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

In passing, it would probably be a good idea to give the matching columns the same name.