# find not exist item in to list A and aexist in list B in ef core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i have to list  and in to list i have list of string :

```
 public async Task<OperationResult<string>> SetAccess(AccessLevelDto accessLevels)
    {
            var access = await GetAccessLevels(accessLevels.RoleId);
    }

 private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAccessLevels(Guid roleId)
    {
        return await AccessLevels.Where(x => x.RoleId == roleId).Select(x => x.Access).ToListAsync();
    }
```

one list : `GetAccessLevels(accessLevels.RoleId)` and second `accessLevels.Access`

i want to find with items exist in list `A` and not exist in list `B` then put then in the `var mustremove` .

**how can i do this ????**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use LINQ to get items in one List<>, that are not in another List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list)

Answer (score 0):

Use "Not Contains" LINQ expression:

```
var listA = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three" };
var listB = new List<string> { "One", "Three" };

var mustremove = listA.Where(x => !listB.Contains(x));
```

*mustremove* will contain one element: "Two"