# C# LINQ DataTable "WHERE NOT IN"

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have two DataTables. I can join these two tables using LINQ but I am trying to write the following SQL query to LINQ but failed.

What is did for joining two DataTables:

```
dtMerged = (from a in dtOraDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                join b in dtSqlSmsTable.AsEnumerable()
                    on a["EntrySerialNo"].ToString() equals b["EntrySerialNo"].ToString()
                    into g
                where g.Any()
                select a).CopyToDataTable();
```

Now I want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM OraSmsData a WHERE EntrySerialNo NOT IN (SELECT EntrySerialNo FROM SqlSmsData WHERE IsProcessed=1);
```

How can I implement this in LINQ? I will appreciate if anyone guide me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something as below:

```
var query = 
  dtOraDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => !dtSqlSmsTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("EntrySerialNo")).Contains(x.Field<decimal>("EntrySerialNo")));
```

Comment: "EntrySerialNo" is sql server numeric datatype. I am getting conversion error.

Comment: Does `int` solved your problem? You can either use `decimal` or `double` if you still get that error.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks @Sowmyadhar. var dtMerged = dtOraDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => !dtSqlSmsTable.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(y => y.Field<decimal>("EntrySerialNo")).Contains(x.Field<decimal>("EntrySerialNo"))).CopyToDataTable();

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
var query =    
    from a in dtOraDataTable.AsEnumerable() 
    where !(from b in dtSqlSmsTable.AsEnumerable()   
            select b["EntrySerialNo"].ToString())    
           .Contains(a["EntrySerialNo"].ToString()    
    select a;
```

Comment: Operator "!" cannot be applied to operand of type 'EnumerableRowCollection<bool>' showing this error.

Comment: I think only one bracket is wrong. The `Contains` check should be outside of `where !(...)` ... like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list)

Comment: Excellent spot, I fixed it now.

Comment: Code with explanation is typically better received that just a dump of code with "try this" or similar...

Comment: "EntrySerialNo" is sql server numeric datatype. I am getting conversion error.