# How to create a list with elements that don't belong to another on C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm fairly new programing and I had a question.

List A is filled with elements of List B, and I want to create a List C with the missing elements from it, using a variable (that is an `int`) as a comparison point.

List A is stored on a Session Variable
List B is taken from my database this way:

```cs
IEnumerable<ListB> Listb = db.ListB; 
List<ListB> Listb = db.ListB.ToList();
```

I tried this solution ([Use LINQ to get items in one List<>, that are not in another List<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944803/use-linq-to-get-items-in-one-list-that-are-not-in-another-list)), but it didn't work for me, or more probably, I couldn't understand it enough to make it work.

Comment: OP, There is no "List A" in your example. Did you accidentally leave it out?

Comment: On my database I have a table, which with the info on ListA, I'm sorry of I didn't specified before, and for the missing elements I meant that ListB is filled with some elements of ListA, and I want ListC to have the element's that are on ListA but not on ListB (Also I used ListA, b, and C here for simplicity's sake, sorry if I make it more confusing, English is not my first language)

Answer (score 3):

Hope you can understand this code.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

List<int> list3 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

I have used [Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-7.0) method here. and its work is clear by its name itself. Give me the item from `list1` except `list2`.

More pictorial description by the pic.

[image]

Comment: Well, OP has a `List<ListB>` not a `List<int>`. So your code will not work if `ListB` doesn't overrride `Equals` and `GetHashCode` or if the same instances are in both lists what is unlikely since the 2nd list comes from a database. `ListB` seems to have an int property that OP wants to use to identify the object.

Comment: @TimSchmelter by the question explanation it looks like OP misunderstood it by List<ListB>

Comment: @TimSchmelter, yeah, you are right on that one, sorry if I make it confusing